# how to make Group Radio Button work

Tags: android, radio-group

basically i dont know how to get my group radio buttons to work i have tried the .isChecked but an error message just pops up, how do i fix this problem

public class CC extends MainActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cc);

    final EditText h = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    final EditText w = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    final EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    final TextView r = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);

    final TextView SUnder = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.suw);
    final TextView Under = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uw);
    final TextView Normal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nor);
    final TextView Over = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ow);
    final TextView MOver = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mo);

    final TextView SUnderT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
    final TextView UnderT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    final TextView NormalT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    final TextView OverT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView11);
    final TextView MOverT = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    final float result=0;

    final RadioGroup group = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    final RadioGroup male = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    final RadioGroup female = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio2);


    Button calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            float height=0;
            float age = 0;
            float weight=0;
            float result=0;

            height= Float.parseFloat(h.getText().toString());
            age= Float.parseFloat(a.getText().toString());
            weight= Float.parseFloat(w.getText().toString());
```

the code below is the problem and i dont know how to fix it

```
            if (male.isChecked)  {

                result = (float) (66.47 + (13.75 * weight) + (5.0 * height) - (6.75 * age));

            }

            if (female.isChecked) {

                result = (float) (665.09 + (9.56 * weight) + (1.84 * height) - (4.67 * age));

            }


}
```

}}

Answer (score 2):

`male` and `female` should be `RadioButton`, not `RadioGroup`. In your XML, they should both be children of the outer `RadioGroup` so that selecting one de-selects the other.

```
<RadioGroup ...>
    <RadioButton .../>
    <RadioButton .../>
</RadioGroup>

final RadioButton male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
final RadioButton female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly i am assuming that male and female are radio buttons and you accidentally declared them as radio groups. In that case you can use the following code.

```
// Get selected radio button from radioGroup    
int selectedId = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId()
// Find the radiobutton by returned id
if(selectedId == R.id.radio1)
{
   result = (float) (66.47 + (13.75 * weight) + (5.0 * height) - (6.75 * age));
}else if(selectedId == R.id.radio2){
  result = (float) (665.09 + (9.56 * weight) + (1.84 * height) - (4.67 * age));
}
```